# Verilog Error in all assignings

Tags: verilog

### Verilog Error

I am trying to learn verilog . This code is made for seven segment led using counter. But I am not able to assign value to nr it gives error. I made a state machine and wish to  get next number on seven segment led after each positive clock.

/*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*/

```
module LED ( nr,clk);

     input  clk;
     output [6:0]nr; //output led seven bit number
     reg [6:0]nr;

     reg [2:0]state;


    always @(posedge clk);
       begin
          state <= 3'b000; // assigning at each clock
          case (state)
          3'b000:
            begin
            nr <= 7'b0000001;  
            state <= 3'b001;
           end

          3'b001:
            begin
            nr <= 7'b0011111;
            state <= 3'b010;

            end

          3'b010:
            begin
            nr <= 7'b0100101;
            state <= 3'b011;

            end

          3'b011:
           begin
           nr <= 7'b0001100;
           state <= 3'b100;

           end

         3'b100:
          begin
          nr <= 7'b1011010;
          state <= 3'b101;

          end

         3'b101:
          begin
          nr <= 7'b1001000;
          state <= 3'b110;

          end

         3'b110:
          begin
          nr <= 7'b1000000;
          state <= 3'b111;

          end

         3'b111:
          begin
          nr <= 7'b0011101;
          state <= 3'b000;

          end

     end

    endmodule
```

Comment: It will be better to tell the error

Comment: got it corrected anyways thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`always @(posedge clk)` no semicolon!

Comment: I did not compile your code. I only looked at it for three seconds. You are missing an endcase.

Comment: got it corrected , had few other issues , trying to learn syntax more precisely now thank you